# Play interstitial ad every 3rd game

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, interstitial, heyzap

I'm using the HeyZap mediation SDK. I have all the mediation set up perfectly fine, but I would like for the interstitial ad to show every 3rd game.

I've tried some solutions here on Stack Overflow but they apply to AdMob.

Right now, I have:

```
-(void) GameOver {
  ....
  [HZInterstitialAd show];
}
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

keep a counter of the number of games played and then only show it if

```
static int count = 0;
-(void) GameOver {
  if(count != 0 && count % 3 == 0)
    [HZInterstitialAd show];

  count++;
}
```

Comment: Xcode is complaining of a "Use of undeclared identifier 'count'. Should I make a property of int with name count?

Comment: Do I increment count like this:  `_count ++;` ?

Comment: yes, you could make a static int so that even if this viewcontroller (or whatever it is) disappears then the static int will persist (cant declare @properties static as far as i know), just declare it above  `- (void) GameOver`

Comment: Yes, that's what I did, but I put the counter above the if statement. Works! Thanks a lot man!

Comment: no problem :) only thing with putting the counter above the if is that it will show on the 2nd GameOver the first time, then every 3rd one after